Premake5 - cppdialect is ignored while creating project for VS2022
I'm trying to compile Sciter from a command line batch, using the Visual Studio 2022 compiler. For that reason I need to generate the VS2022 projects using Premake5.
However Sciter needs to be compiled with C++17. Premake5 provides a cppdialect option to configure that. But this option is completely ignored while my projects are generated.
Below is the Lua code I'm using with Premake5:
newoption {
   trigger     = "device",
   value       = "DESKTOP|HANDHELD|IOT",
   description = "target device",
   default     = "DESKTOP",
   allowed = {
      { "DESKTOP",   "Desktop machine" },
      { "HANDHELD",  "Mobile device" },
      { "IOT",       "IoT device" }
   }
}

newoption {
   trigger     = "OPENGL",
   value       = "GL|GLES",
   description = "OpenGL support",
   default     = "GL",
   allowed = {
      { "GL",   "OpenGL" },
      { "GLES",  "OpenGLES" }
   }
}

newoption {
    trigger     = "VULKAN",
    description = "VULKAN support",
}

newoption {
    trigger     = "METAL",
    description = "METAL support (MacOS/iOS)",
}

newoption {
    trigger     = "DX12",
    description = "DX12 support (Windows)",
}


SDKDIR = "sdk.js"
BUILDDIR = "build.js"

defines { 
  "SCITERJS", "SCRIPT_JS",
  "JS_STRICT_NAN_BOXING", 
  "CONFIG_BIGNUM",
  "CONFIG_UNITS",  
  "CONFIG_JSX", 
  "CONFIG_JSX_SCITER",
  "CONFIG_DEBUGGER",
  "CONFIG_STORAGE",
  "CONFIG_OBJECT_LITERAL_CALL"
}

filter { "options:VULKAN" }
  defines {"USE_VULKAN", "SK_VULKAN"}
  includedirs { "$(VK_SDK_PATH)/Include" }  

filter { "options:METAL" }
  defines {"USE_METAL", "SK_METAL"}

filter { "options:DX12" }
  defines {"USE_DX12", "SK_DIRECT3D"}

filter { "options:OPENGL=GL" }
  defines {"USE_OPENGL", "SK_GL"}

filter { "options:OPENGL=GLES" }
  defines {"USE_OPENGLES", "SK_GL"}

filter {}

MONOLITHIC = true -- by design
USE_SKIA_BY_DEFAULT = true -- only rendering option on devices
WINDOWLESS = true

defines { "WINDOWLESS", "MONOLITHIC", "SCITER_BUILD",
          "DEVICE=" .. _OPTIONS["device"] }


include "premake5-modules.lua"

configurations { "Debug", "Release" }
platforms { "x32", "x64","arm32", "arm64" } 


function osabbr() 
  return os.target()
end

filter "system:windows"
  preferredtoolarchitecture "x86_64"
  --buildoptions "-Zm200"
  defines { "NOMINMAX" }
  location(BUILDDIR .. "/" .. osabbr())  
  platforms { "x32", "x64", "arm32", "arm64" }
  --configurations { "DebugSkia", "ReleaseSkia" }
  defines { "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" } 
  systemversion "latest"

filter "system:macosx"
  location(BUILDDIR .. "/" .. osabbr())  
  platforms { "x64" }  
filter "system:linux"
  location(BUILDDIR .. "/" .. osabbr() .. "/" .. string.lower(_OPTIONS["device"]))
  platforms { "x64", "arm32", "arm64" }  
filter "system:android"
  location(BUILDDIR .. "/" .. osabbr())  
  platforms { "x32", "x64", "arm32", "arm64" }  
filter {}


includedirs { 
  ".",     
  "engine",
  "engine/tool",
  "engine/gool",
  "engine/html",
  "engine/external/uv/include",
  "engine/external/uv-tls/include",
  "engine/external/zlib",
  "engine/external/minizip"
}  

filter "not system:linux"
  flags { "MultiProcessorCompile" } -- does not work reliably on Linux, why?
filter{}

cppdialect "C++17"
cdialect "C99"

staticruntime "On"

filter "platforms:x32"
  architecture "x86"
filter "platforms:x64"
  architecture "x86_64" 
filter "platforms:arm32"
  architecture "ARM" 
filter "platforms:arm64"
  architecture "ARM64" 

filter {"platforms:x32", "system:windows"}
  defines { "WIN32" }
filter {"platforms:x64", "system:windows"}
  defines { "WIN32","WIN64" }      
filter {"platforms:arm64", "system:windows"}
  defines { "WIN32","WIN64","ARM64" }      
  architecture "ARM64" 

filter "configurations:Debug*"
  defines { "DEBUG", "_DEBUG" }
  symbols "On"

filter "configurations:Release*"
  defines { "NDEBUG"}  
  optimize "Full"
  -- symbols "Off"
  flags { "LinkTimeOptimization" }

filter {"system:windows"}
  defines { "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" } 

filter { "system:macosx", "configurations:Release*" }
  linkoptions { "-s", "-flto=full" }

filter "system:linux"
  defines { "_GNU_SOURCE" }
  buildoptions {
    "`pkg-config fontconfig --cflags`",
    "-fPIC",
    "-Wno-unknown-pragmas",
    "-Wno-write-strings",
  }
  linkoptions { 
    "-fPIC",
    "-pthread",
    "-ldl",     
  } 

filter { "system:linux", "platforms:x32 or x64" }
  buildoptions {
    "-march=nehalem",
  }

filter { "system:linux", "platforms:arm32" }
  -- rapsberry Pi 2 and above
  buildoptions {
    "-mfpu=neon",
    "-mfloat-abi=hard",
  }
  linkoptions {
    "-mfpu=neon",
    "-mfloat-abi=hard",
  }


filter { "toolset:gcc", "files:*.cpp" }
  buildoptions {
    "-fpermissive",
    "-Wno-reorder",
  }

filter "system:android"
  buildoptions { "-fexceptions" }
  --optimize "Off"


filter {}

skia_includes()


workspace "sciter.lite"

--|
--| sciter dll
--|

project "sciter.lite"
  kind "SharedLib"
  language "C++"

  defines { "SCITER_EXPORTS" }
 
  filter "system:android"
    toolset "clang"
    --optimize "Off"
    defines { "ANDROID" }

  filter{}

  targetname "sciter"

  include_files_lite()
  include_files_tool()
  include_files_uv()
  include_files_uv_tls()  
  include_files_dybase()
  include_files_gool()
  include_files_zlib()
  include_files_minizip()
  include_files_png()
  include_files_jpeg()
  include_files_webp()
  include_files_rlottie()
  include_files_html()
  include_files_http()
  include_files_tmt()
  include_files_xdomjs()
  include_files_qjs()

  if os.target() == "windows" then
    --include_files_directshow()
    include_files_d2d()
  end
  --if os.target() == "linux" then    
  --  include_files_gtk()
  --elseif os.target() == "macosx" then
  --  include_files_osx()
  --end  
  include_files_xgl_skia()
  include_files_webgl() 
  include_freetype_files()

  filter "system:windows"
    prebuildcommands { 
        "subwcrev.exe \"%{wks.location}..\\..\" \"%{wks.location}..\\..\\engine\\sciter-revision-template.h\" \"%{wks.location}..\\..\\engine\\sciter-revision.h\"",
        "\"%{wks.location}..\\..\\".. SDKDIR .. "\\bin\\windows\\packfolder.exe\" \"%{wks.location}..\\..\\engine\\res.js\" \"%{wks.location}..\\..\\engine\\master-css-resources-js.cpp\"  -v \"master_css_resources\"" }
  filter {}

  targetdir (SDKDIR .. "/bin.lite/" .. osabbr() .. "/%{cfg.platform}")


  filter "system:windows"
    links { "usp10", "ws2_32", "wininet", "windowscodecs" }
    files { 
      "engine/lite/windows/dllmain.cpp",       
      "engine/lite/windows/sciter.def", 
      "engine/lite/windows/sciter.dll.rc", 
      "engine/lite/windows/lite-d2d.cpp", 
    }

  filter "system:macosx"
    links { 
      "CoreFoundation.framework", 
      "Cocoa.framework",
      "Carbon.framework", 
      "AVFoundation.framework",
      "SystemConfiguration.framework",
      "CoreMedia.framework",
      "CoreText.framework",
      "CoreGraphics.framework",
      "CoreData.framework",
      "CoreVideo.framework",
      "IOKit.framework",
      "OpenGL.framework"
    } 

  filter "system:linux"
    linkoptions { 
       "`pkg-config fontconfig --libs`",
       "-fPIC",
       "-pthread",
       "-Wl,--no-undefined",
       "-lX11", "-lX11-xcb",
       "-ldl",
       "-latomic",
    }

  filter { "system:linux", "options:OPENGL=GL" }
    linkoptions { 
       "-lGL",
       "-lGLU"
    }
  filter { "system:linux", "options:OPENGL=GLES" }
    linkoptions { 
       "-lGL",
       "-lEGL",
       "-lGLESv2",
    }

  filter "system:android"
    buildoptions { "-Wreorder" }
    links {"GLESv2","GLESv1_CM","EGL","m"}

  filter {}  

workspace "sciter.lite.static"

project "sciter.lite.static"
  kind "StaticLib"
  language "C++"

  defines { "STATIC_LIB" }
  
  targetname "sciter.static"

  targetdir (BUILDDIR .. "/lib." .. osabbr() .."/%{cfg.platform}lite")

  includedirs { 
    "engine/tiscript/include" 
  }

  include_files_lite()
  include_files_tool()
  include_files_uv()
  include_files_uv_tls()  
  include_files_dybase()
  include_files_gool()
  include_files_zlib()
  include_files_png()
  include_files_jpeg()
  include_files_webp()
  include_files_rlottie()
  include_files_html()
  include_files_http()
  include_files_tmt()
  include_files_xdom()
  include_files_xgl_skia()      
  include_files_webgl()  
  include_freetype_files()

  filter "system:macosx"
    links { 
      "CoreFoundation.framework", 
      "Cocoa.framework",
      "Carbon.framework", 
      "AVFoundation.framework",
      "SystemConfiguration.framework",
      "CoreMedia.framework",
      "CoreText.framework",
      "CoreGraphics.framework",
      "CoreData.framework",
      "CoreVideo.framework",
      "IOKit.framework",
      "OpenGL.framework"
    } 
  filter {}  

-- include "sdk"

This code is called from the following batch file:
premake5.exe vs2022
premake5.exe vs2022 --file="premake5-lite.lua"
cd sdk.js
premake5.exe vs2022
cd ..

As you can see, the cppdialect "C++17" option is defined in the Lua code, but completely ignored. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

"...What's New in 5.0...vs2012, vs2013, vs2015, vs2019 (Visual Studio 2012, 2013, 2015, 2019)..." https://premake.github.io/docs/Whats-New-in-5.0  no mention of 2022.

I don't know about cppdialect, but you can directly set compiler option with buildoptions { "-std=c++17" }. This is how I am doing on our code based using an outdated version of Premake5. And with a tiny patch it can support VS2022.

cppdialect should work (you might check in generated solution that your have /std:c++17 flag). You probably need filter { "toolset:msc*" } buildoptions {"/Zc:__cplusplus"} -- else __cplusplus would be 199711L

@prapin @Jarod42 unfortunately your suggestions doesn't resolve the issue. After my projects are generated they contain the following option: <LanguageStandard>stdcpplatest</LanguageStandard>. However I need this option to be configured this way: <LanguageStandard>stdcpp17</LanguageStandard>. I tried your suggestions, but they had no impact at all on the generated projects, and the cppdialect option definitively don't work.

From https://github.com/premake/premake-core/blob/master/modules/vstudio/vs2010_vcxproj.lua#L1746 it should be as expected... Would it be possible that one of your include also uses cppdialect?

@Jarod42 no unfortunately, I checked the includes and there are no cppdialect hidden in them.

Can you share a (github) link to try to reproduce the error? I do have project using cdddialect "C++17" correctly. (premake has even test case for that).
